# Rm command recovery for this situation

Tags: files, rm, data-recovery

İn my desktop, i have a dir. called exam, and i wanted to remove it from the console and wrote `rm * /exam`, and apparently it removed some other files from my desktop. Please tell me that there is a way for a recovery.

Edit: i am not even sure which files are removed, so i dont know their file names.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which directory you were in when you ran that command you most likely deleted the files that were there as well. There are a couple of tools that I've used in the past but I think you might be out of luck.

Depending on the types of data one of 2 programs may help.

- [ext3grep](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/undelete_ext3.html) (general)
- [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (images & media files, as well as many other document and archive types)
- [Ext4magic](http://openfacts2.berlios.de/wikien/index.php/BerliosProject%3aExt4magic) (friendlier frontend to ext3grep)
- [R-Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) (undelete tools)
- [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) (Live CD/DVD for data recovery)

But installing them could likely overwrite the data you're trying to recover!

If I were you, I'd download [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download) burn it to a CD or USB thumb drive and boot the system with the files using it. SystemRescueCd includes tools for undeleting files. I'd give that a try.

#### References

- [ext3grep google code project page](https://code.google.com/p/ext3grep/)
- [tutorial on using ext3grep - good for getting started](http://wiki.itadmins.net/doku.php?id=filesystems%3aext3grep)

Comment: i ran it on the desktop directory, there are like 6-7 files missing which i can tell from the appearance of my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Most command line commands take a space separated list of files or folders as input. `*` means everything, so running `rm * /exam` means delete everything in the current folder and then delete `/exam`. In other words, you have deleted all files (not folders) from your Desktop. The only thing you can do is to try recover them using such tools as [suggested by @slm.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74857/22222)

You should also be aware that even if you had run the command you wanted to run, `rm /exam`, it would not have worked. By default, `rm` does not delete directories, only files. In order to use it to delete a directory, it needs the recursive (`-r`) flag. So, to delete the directory `/exam`, you would need to run `rm -r /exam`.

One way of protecting yourself from this sort if error in the future is to make `rm` an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) to `rm -i` or `rm -I`, so you will be asked to confirm file deletions. From the `rm` man page:

```
   -i     prompt before every removal

   -I     prompt  once  before removing more than three files, or
          when removing recursively.   Less  intrusive  than  -i,
          while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

To make `rm` an alias to `rm -i`, add this line tou your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some setups stash deleted files away, check if that is your case (I doubt it). Otherwise, write it up to learning that Unix does *exactly* as told, it doesn't try to second guess you. Ever.